# Equivalent of matcher.start and matcher.end in c#

Tags: java, c#

I am new to c# and  trying to convert below code into c# but can not find any api in c# to do so.

1. Please explain equivalent of matcher.start() and matcher.end().
2. what is equivalent of matcher.group() in c#.

   ```
   private String getFinalVariant(String strInputWord) {

   Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[aeiouhy]+");
   Matcher mat = pat.matcher(strInputWord);
   int lenghtOfInputWord = strInputWord.length();
   while (mat.find()) {
       if (mat.start() == 0) {

           int index = '1';
           Map<String, String> temp = ruleList[index];
           if (temp.containsKey(mat.group())) {
               strInputWord = strInputWord.replaceFirst(mat.group(), temp.get(mat.group()));
           }

       } else if (mat.end()== lenghtOfInputWord) {

           int index = '3';
           int lastIndex = strInputWord.lastIndexOf(mat.group());
           Map<String, String> temp = ruleList[index];
           if (temp.containsKey(mat.group())) {
               String tail = strInputWord.substring(lastIndex).replaceFirst(mat.group(), temp.get(mat.group()));
               strInputWord = strInputWord.substring(0, lastIndex) + tail;
           }

       } else {

           int index = '2';
           Map<String, String> temp = ruleList[index];
           String str = mat.group();
           // System.out.println(str);
           //  System.out.println(mat.start());
           if (temp.containsKey(mat.group())) {
               if (strInputWord.length() > 3) {
                   int index1 = strInputWord.indexOf(mat.group(), 1);
                   if (index1 != 0 && index1 != strInputWord.length() - 1) {
                       String matched = strInputWord.substring(index1, strInputWord.length() - 1).replaceFirst(mat.group(), temp.get(mat.group()));
                       strInputWord = strInputWord.substring(0, index1) + matched + strInputWord.charAt(strInputWord.length() - 1);
                   }

               } else if (strInputWord.length() == 3) {
                   strInputWord = strInputWord.charAt(0) + strInputWord.substring(1, 2).replaceFirst(mat.group(), temp.get(mat.group())) + strInputWord.charAt(strInputWord.length() - 1);
               }

           }

       }

   }
   return strInputWord;
   }
   ```

Comment: Have you looked at the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match` class?

Comment: Yes i did but did not find any equivalent of match.end

Comment: How closely did you look at the properties? (Hint: just because there aren't properties called Start and End doesn't mean the equivalent information isn't available. There isn't that much to look through...)

Comment: Try `match.Index + match.Length`.

Comment: (If you look for "C# regular expressions tutorial" there are a lot of hits, btw...)

Comment: Ok , is match.Index  equivalent to match.start and match.end is equivalent to (match.Index + match.Length) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(yourString);
```

This will return all matches. Each match is an object of type Match, which has an Index property you can use to work out the first and last match.

For group() you can use the same collection to iterate through the different matches.